# In Codeigniter 3.0, Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on boolean in C:\mypath\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_database_driver.php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I try to setup session in database. but seem not work.

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

**Source code**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Show us the code sample that doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have updated the source code.
But it's a normal code~

Comment: I have the same problem too but the function that gives me the error  is `num_rows()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `application/config/config.php` file setting to

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';//its your table name name
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Read  [Session Preferences](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences)

Don't forget it to load via `autoload.php` or loading `$this->load->library('session');` before use it.

Answer (score 0):

First change your application/config/config.php setting to:

```
 $config['log_threshold'] = 1;
 $config['db_log_enabled'] = FALSE;
```

You'll get a more informative error in your log. You can find the logs in:

```
 /application/logs/
```

There is a CI bug involving ipv6 ip addresses.  You are experiencing this bug if If the primary error looks like:

```
 ERROR - 2016-11-20 09:59:03 --> Severity: Warning --> mysqli::query(): (42000/3057): Incorrect user-level lock name 'longrandomsessionnamestring_2001:db8:1234:1:567::1'. /var/www/html/www/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 305
```

You can verify that this is the issue by accessing your site directly via its ipv4 address (you should no longer get this error).

If you get the error via ipv6, but not via ipv4 you can alleviate the problem by setting

```
 $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
```

or, better, apply CI hot fix #4916 to your CI code

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/e49aa1f1cb63ad90d6c2d204439f538dcc282243